# Insert " " into formula with variables VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert a vlookup into a range of cells that is defined by variables.
My problem is that the search criteria (I gave the variable the name x) in the vlookup needs to be in " ", else the vlookup doesnt work.

But if I insert those " " into the formula in any way VBA thinks I'm trying to let it take x as a value.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

If there is anything else wrong with the code, please tell me too, I'm new to this.

```
Sub FindExchange()

n = Worksheets.Count
For k = n To 6 Step -1

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(k)

Dim lColumn As Long
    lColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For i = lColumn To 1 Step -4

Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

x = Cells(1, i).Value

ws.Range(Cells(2, i + 2), Cells(lrow, i + 2)).FormulaLocal = "=vlookup(" & x & ";Sheet1!$B$2:$C$832;2;FALSE)"

Next i
Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the double quotes `"` just add `Chr(34)`.

change your `FormulaLocal` string to:

```
"=VLookup(" & chr(34) & x & chr(34) & ";Sheet1!$B$2:$C$832;2;FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution ,

```
"=vlookup(""" & x & """,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$832,2,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"=vlookup(" & """" & x & """" & ";Sheet1!$B$2:$C$832;2;FALSE)"
```